# Laravel выдает ошибку моделей: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется модель

```
<?php
// Model
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
class BlogModel extends Model
{
    public function getIndex() {
        $data = DB::table('blog')->get();
        return $data;
    }
    public function getReview() {
        $vk = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/board.getComments?group_id=66170841&topic_id=29616489");
        return $vk;
    }
}
```

И контроллер:

```
<?php 
// Controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\BlogModel;
use DB;
class BlogController extends Controller 
{
    public function index(BlogModel $data)
    {
        $data = $data->getIndex();
        $vk = $data->getReview;
        var_dump($vk);
        return view('layouts/index',[
            'data'=>$data
        ]);
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку

> Trying to get property of non-object

Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вы перезаписываете переменную `$data`

Попробуйте так

```
<?php 
// Controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\BlogModel;
use DB;
class BlogController extends Controller 
{
    public function index(BlogModel $model)
    {
        $data = $model->getIndex();
        $vk = $model->getReview;
        // Подозреваю, что getReview необходимо заменить на getReview();
        var_dump($vk);
        return view('layouts/index',[
            'data'=>$data
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

возникает, когда ты обращаешься к свойству объекта, а самого объекта не существует. Например это вызовет подобную ошибку:

```
$object = false; // например ищешь ты по бд и неудачно. 
echo $object->name; // эта строка вызовет ошибку, потому что $object не имеет свойства name
```

В твоем случае:

```
public function index(BlogModel $data) // здесь $data это объект

$data = $data->getIndex(); // а здесь ты затер свой объект и записал туда другое значение
$vk = $data->getReview; // и пытаешься обратиться к свойству объекта, который ты уже затер выше.
```

Правильное решение показали в предыдущем ответе.